# How to read a text from a specific world in a text tell the next space in the text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, text

i have a text file that contain a switch names and the port for every switch like this as an example:

```
switch 1
[1] server 1
[2] server 2
[3] server 3
[4] server 4

 some text that no one need 

 switch 2
 [1] server 1
 [2] server 2
 [3] server 3
 [4] server 4
```

now what i want to do is to split the text where the split start when its read switch 1 and stop when its read a space or empty line and the problem ist that i have som text that i dont need in the middel any help please

Thanx in Advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, you want to keep all lines that:

1. Start with the word `switch`
2. Follow after line beginning with `switch` but before the next empty line

That's not too hard:

```
keptlines = []
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('switch '):
            keptlines.append(line)
            for line in f:  # Continue iterating f for additional lines to keep
                if not line.rstrip():
                    break  # We hit an empty line, return to looking for switch
                keptlines.append(line)
```

There are variant approaches if you want to keep the various switches separate (e.g. a `dict` keyed by switch number, with `list`s of lines as the values), but this is the basic pattern.

Just for completeness, there is a variant approach to simplify the code using `itertools`, adding an import at the top of the file `from itertools import takewhile` and replacing:

```
            for line in f:  # Continue iterating f for additional lines to keep
                if not line.rstrip():
                    break  # We hit an empty line, return to looking for switch
                keptlines.append(line)
```

with just:

```
            keptlines.extend(takewhile(str.rstrip, f))
```

A similar approach could push the outer loop into a `dropwhile` call, but that would get pretty complicated (you couldn't remove the `dropwhile` wrapper without losing data, and you'd have to rewrap it for each new `switch` block), so it's probably not worth it.

Comment: thank you very much, its worked perfect i spend all the day on the internet searching for a solution for this problem  once again thanks a lot .  :)